# How to know if a task is executing in background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, background

In my app I'm downloading lots of images on a method.

I'm using a

```
 downloadTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
                   beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

                       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:downloadTask]; 
                       downloadTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

                   }];
```

This is working fine, if I press the home or sleep button, the images continue downloading.

I'm showing the progress in a UIProgressView inside an UIAlertView, and when the percent is 100% the alertView is dissmised and I change the viewController to other where I show the donwloaded images.
But I only want this to happen if the app is really active at the moment the download finish.

I have been looking at the app state and while it's downloading with the screen off.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState
```

the state is UIApplicationStateActive during all the donwload

How can I can know if the downloading is happening with the screen off or on?

EDITED AFTER ACCEPTING THE ANSWER:

I just discovered, if I tap the home button, the app enters in UIApplicationStateBackground, if I tap the wake/sleep it enters in UIApplicationStateInactive

Following the approach of the correct answer, my app contines donwloading in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>The screen is off in two states (apart from when the app has not been even opened):</del>

- <del>**suspended** : in this case you don't have to worry because the download won't procede until the app gets active again;  It will enter this state on</del>
- <del>**background** : it's in this state for a limited amount of time before going in suspend, and the screen is already off in this moment. Here you may want to check then whether to do all the things you said or not, because in this state code can be still executed. In this state the app status is **UIApplicationStateBackground**, so you could just perform a check like this:</del>

You probably want to check whether the app is in background execution in order to achieve the result. Just like this:

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] != UIApplicationStateBackground) {
  // Do stuff  
}
```

If it's in background, so the screen is off.

**UPDATE**: after few test, what I figured out is that the behaviour you are expieriencing is probably due to the execution of the download on the main thread.

You should send the download on (for instance) the global queue. This way the application will enter the background state as expected:

```
....
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.bti];
    }];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self doBackgroundStuff];
});
....
```

This way, if the app is put on background while the download is in progress, the application state will turn into **UIApplicationStateBackground**, and then you can check it as I wrote initially. If you are doing UI updates during the progress remember to send them back to the main thread (because the download is now on a different one).

Comment: But it seem that using beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler, the app don't enter in background mode until the task is finished, but the screen is off. If I start the download task and turn off the screen, it always has UIApplicationStateActive state and donwload all the images

Comment: uhm, this looks quite weird... in *doBackgroundStuff* you should just put the call to the function that starts the download. In the connection handlers, then, there should be the check on the app state to see whether it's background or not. If it doesn't work, could you please post a bit more code? Because there must be some thing I'm missing on your case

Comment: Doing what you said makes the app to enter background and change to inactive while it continues donwloading. Do the download with the screen off is made in UIApplicationStateInactive state.
It's now what I was looking for, but now at least, it seems that now I can see if the app is active or inactive while the downloading, and continues working as I expected when I turn on the screen, so I accept it as valid answer. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted a comment, but seems that you read it before I deleted, I was wrong in that one.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether your app is running in the background or not by setting a flag in the designated application delegate methods`applicationDidEnterBackground:` and `applicationWillEnterForeground:`. Example:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
    _applicationRunsInForeground = NO;
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    _applicationRunsInForeground = YES;
}
```

If you don't want to have this `_applicationRunsInForeground` flag inside your application delegate, you could observe the delegate's NSNotifications in your viewcontroller class instead (`UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` and `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`).

Comment: The problem is, the applicationDidEnterBackground is not called until the app finish the background task

Comment: That's impossible. The applicationDidEnterBackground delegate method will always be called when the user taps the home button or when the the user presses the sleep/wake button on their device.